# Override hosts variable of Ansible playbook from the command line

Tags: ansible

This is a fragment of a playbook that I'm using (`server.yml`):

```
- name: Determine Remote User
  hosts: web
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - { role: remote-user, tags: [remote-user, always] }
```

My hosts file has different groups of servers, e.g.

```
[web]
x.x.x.x

[droplets]
x.x.x.x
```

Now I want to execute `ansible-playbook -i hosts/<env> server.yml` and override `hosts: web` from `server.yml` to run this playbook for `[droplets]`.

Can I just override as a one time off thing, without editing `server.yml` directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I don't think Ansible provides this feature, which it should. Here's something that you can do:

`hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('web') }}"`

and you can pass `variable_host` from either command-line or from a vars file, e.g.:

```
ansible-playbook server.yml --extra-vars "variable_host=newtarget(s)"
```

Comment: A small correction required. It should be `hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('web')}}"`

Comment: Here is a note that I feel would complete the answer for ansible newbies searching for this solution:
Example: `ansible-playbook server.yml --extra-vars "variable_host=newtarget(s)"`

Comment: **WHEN** (ie in what order) does ansible parse variables Variables in `group_vars/all` appears to be parsed **after** the `hosts:` line of the playbook. However, variables in `vars:` and variables in `vars_files:` are parsed before the `hosts:` line? **NOTE** I am _not_ asking about precedence.

Comment: You can use also `-e` instead of `--extra-vars`.

Comment: Look at other answers for more details

Comment: The method doesn't seem like handling host exclusion. For example: `ansible-playbook server.yml --extra-vars "variable_host=newtarget:!subset"`

Comment: This method also works with cloud provider group_names, such as AWS tags. `--extra-vars "myhosts=tag_Name_myinstancename"` or `-e "myhosts=us_west_2:&tag_env_production"`. This is super handy if you have a playbook that you want to apply to multiple deployed environments.

Comment: I thought that `newtarget(s)` was a function, and `s` a parameter. `newtarget(s)` means the name of a host: _newtarget_ (in singular), or the names of multiple hosts: _newtargets_ (in plural).

Comment: Another solution is to use the special variable `ansible_limit` which is the contents of the `--limit` option for the current execution of Ansible: `hosts: "{{ ansible_limit | default(omit) }}"`. See my answer below.

Comment: Was using Ansible 2.9, passing array to host field didn't work. Instead had to use 'add_host' module which gets a group which will be passed on to the 'host' field

Answer (score 73):

For anyone who might come looking for the solution. 
**Play Book**

```
- hosts: '{{ host }}'
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="Host is {{ ansible_fqdn }}"
```

**Inventory**

```
[web]
x.x.x.x

[droplets]
x.x.x.x
```

**Command:** `ansible-playbook deplyment.yml -i hosts --extra-vars "host=droplets"`
So you can specify the group name in the extra-vars

Comment: Note, be careful with var naming. I was testing this using `play_hosts` and not getting the expected results because I forgot that `play_hosts` is an internal Ansible var for all the hosts in the current play.

Comment: I suppose default should be set as in the answer above.

Answer (score 43):

We use a simple [fail](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html#fail-module) task to force the user to specify the Ansible [limit option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html?highlight=limit#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-l), so that we don't execute on all hosts by default/accident.

The easiest way I found is this:

```yaml
---
- name: Force limit
  # 'all' is okay here, because the fail task will force the user to specify a limit on the command line, using -l or --limit
  hosts: 'all'

  tasks:
  - name: checking limit arg
    fail:
      msg: "you must use -l or --limit - when you really want to use all hosts, use -l 'all'"
    when: ansible_limit is not defined
    run_once: true
```

Now we must use the `-l` (= `--limit` option) when we run the playbook, e.g.

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -l www.example.com
```

[Limit option docs](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/commands/):

> Limit to one or more hosts This is required when one wants to run a
> playbook against a host group, but only against one or more members of
> that group.
>
> Limit to **one host**
>
> `ansible-playbook playbooks/PLAYBOOK_NAME.yml --limit "host1"`
>
> Limit to **multiple hosts**
>
> `ansible-playbook playbooks/PLAYBOOK_NAME.yml --limit "host1,host2"`
>
> **Negated limit.**
> NOTE: Single quotes MUST be used to prevent bash
> interpolation.
>
> `ansible-playbook playbooks/PLAYBOOK_NAME.yml --limit 'all:!host1'`
>
> Limit to **host group**
>
> `ansible-playbook playbooks/PLAYBOOK_NAME.yml --limit 'group1'`

Comment: perhaps there's an Ansible plugin that can enforce the check?

Answer (score 26):

This is a bit late, but I think you could use the `--limit or -l` command to limit the pattern to more specific hosts. (version 2.3.2.0)

You could have

`- hosts: all (or group)
  tasks:
  - some_task`

and then `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -l some_more_strict_host_or_pattern`
and use the `--list-hosts` flag to see on which hosts this configuration would be applied.

Comment: I'm very new to ansible but I consider this a very effective solution, much more compact than the others. Why was it downvoted?

Comment: This is dangerous. In case one forgets to `limit` the list of hosts affected the playbook may cause a lot of damage.

Comment: I find that using `--extra-vars "variable_host=newtarget(s)"` just like the accepted solution is as dangerous and a more complicated solution. It uses a default hosts of `web` which could be applied here as well instead of `all`. You could use a strict hosts group as default to avoid making a mistake and use the `--list-hosts` flag to have a clear understanding of which hosts you are affecting.

Comment: I completely agree, there is nothing worse about this approach than the accepted answer. If you use "all" as default with the accepted approach, then you are in just as much trouble. If you use something other than "all" with this approach you are just as safe. So this is a better solution as it requires less code an uses built in functionality for just this purpose. +1.

Comment: Solution with extra-vars allows to specify empty group (or non-existing) as default value. So if you forget to provide the variable via command line nothing bad happens.

Solution with "--limit"option more dangerous because the playbook could not use empty group as default value for the hosts. Option "--llmit" is applied to the hosts value hence it will be applied to the empty groups and will provide empty result. So you HAVE to use "all" or some other non-empty host as default value. And some day you will forget to provide "--limit" argument and playbook will be applied to all hosts.

Comment: I think arguments are valid for both sides. In production, this method is a bit risky where in the accepted solution a 'null' group can be used for saftey. But in testing and development I think your solution is superior. imho both solutions should be accepted since the requester didn't specify if this is for testing or production.

Comment: @sudosoul the `limit` flag will to an intersection of the given hosts and the limit pattern. If `host: undefined`, no hosts will ever be used.

Comment: @JonathanHamel Yeah just realized that. Check out the answer though I just posted, I think it solves the issue of using limit.

Comment: This should be combined with @TmTron's answer to catch the case where the caller failed to supply `--limit` (otherwise it will affect all possible hosts, which may not be the behaviour you want)

Answer (score 23):

An other solution is to use the special variable `ansible_limit` which is the contents of the `--limit` CLI option for the current execution of Ansible.

```
- hosts: "{{ ansible_limit | default(omit) }}"
```

If the `--limit` option is omitted, then Ansible issues a warning, but does nothing since no host matched.

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: None

PLAY ****************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest method of handling this, and is safe.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution indeed. You may even consider a useful group/host instead of using omit. That way, you can deploy always on a test system and when you are ready for production, you provide the server via --limit.

Comment: Could you please add a small example to make it clear.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using another approach that doesn't need any inventory and works with this simple command:

```
ansible-playbook site.yml -e working_host=myhost
```

To perform that, you need a playbook with two plays:

- first play runs on localhost and add a host (from given variable) in a known group in inmemory inventory
- second play runs on this known group

A working example (copy it and runs it with previous command):

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name: "{{ working_host }}"
      groups: working_group
    changed_when: false

- hosts: working_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "I'm on {{ ansible_host }}"
```

> I'm using ansible 2.4.3 and 2.3.3

Comment: But why would I want to deploy always on localhorst?
You may consider using the variable working_horst instead of localhost, skipping the task add_host.

Answer (score 9):

I changed mine to default to no host and have a check to catch it. That way the user or cron is forced to provide a single host or group etc. I like the logic from the comment from @wallydrag. The `empty_group` contains no hosts in the inventory.

```
- hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('empty_group') }}"
```

Then add the check in tasks:

```
   tasks:
   - name: Fail script if required variable_host parameter is missing
     fail:
       msg: "You have to add the --extra-vars='variable_host='"
     when: (variable_host is not defined) or (variable_host == "")
```

Answer (score 7):

Just came across this googling for a solution. Actually, there is one in Ansible 2.5. You can specify your inventory file with `--inventory`, like this: `ansible --inventory configs/hosts --list-hosts all`

Comment: I believe this is the most correct answer in the Year of Our Lord 2019. From Ansible 2.8.4's -h: `-i INVENTORY, --inventory=INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host path or comma separated host
                        list. --inventory-file is deprecated`

Comment: This works great for me and lets me use an input parameter as the `inventory` argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a task that's associated with a host, but on different host, you should try [delegate_to](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

In your case, you should delegate to your localhost (ansible master) and calling `ansible-playbook` command

Answer (score 3):

I am using ansible 2.5 (2.5.3 exactly), and it seems that the *vars file* is loaded before the hosts param is executed. So you can set the host in a **vars.yml** file and just write `hosts: {{ host_var }}` in your playbook

For example, in my playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_name }}"
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - vars/project.yml
  tasks:
    ...
```

And inside vars/project.yml:

```
---

# general
host_name: your-fancy-host-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cool solution I came up to safely specify hosts via the `--limit` option. In this example, the play will end if the playbook was executed without any hosts specified via the `--limit` option.

This was tested on Ansible version 2.7.10

```
---
- name: Playbook will fail if hosts not specified via --limit option.
  # Hosts must be set via limit. 
  hosts: "{{ play_hosts }}"
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      inventory_hosts: []
  - set_fact:
      inventory_hosts: "{{inventory_hosts + [item]}}"
    with_items: "{{hostvars.keys()|list}}"

  - meta: end_play
    when: "(play_hosts|length) == (inventory_hosts|length)"

  - debug:
      msg: "About to execute tasks/roles for {{inventory_hostname}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as I am using Azure devops to deploy an application using CICD pipelines. I had to make this hosts (in yml file) more dynamic so in release pipeline I can add it's value, for example:

[--extra-vars "host=$(target_host)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8XRO.png)

[pipeline_variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhu7k.png)

My ansible playbook looks like this

```
- name: Apply configuration to test nodes
  hosts: '{{ host }}'
```