# Ansible: overwrite inventory's ansible_host from command line

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a simple inventory in `hosts`:

```
dockermachine ansible_host=10.10.10.10
```

I need to be able to provide any other IP I wish from the command line, overwriting the default, something like:
`ansible-playbook -i hosts@dockermachine.ansible_host=11.11.11.11 site.yml`

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override hosts variable of Ansible playbook from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222641/override-hosts-variable-of-ansible-playbook-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @3sky: I tried this, and I get "skipping: no hosts matched", since the new IP is not inside of hosts. In that question there was a need to switch between host groups "web"/"droplets" which were defined in advance. I need to provide an arbitrary IP on the command line.

Comment: Because: `I don't think Ansible provides this feature` :) If You really need that, try to modify `hosts` with sed, and run playbook. `sed -i.bak "/dockermachine ansible_host=10.10.10.10/c\dockermachine ansible_host=11.11.11.11" hosts | ansible-playbook ...| mv hosts.bak hosts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your inventory is really that simple, you can probably live without the hostname. Remove the entry from your current default inventory. Make sure your playbook is targeted against the `all` group and launch your playbook with a single host ip inventory:

```
ansible-playbook -i 10.10.10.11, my_playbook.yml
```

Note: the trailing comma after the IP is not a mistake, it needs to be there so that the IP after `-i` parameter is interpreted as a [comma separated list of hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-i) and not as an inventory file path.