# Only allow `--check` and / or `--diff` for certain Ansible hosts / groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to restrict Ansible deployment actions to *dry-run* only (i.e. `--check` and / or `--diff`) for certain hosts / groups.

The best I was able to come up with, is to check in every playbook, maybe as a `pre_task`, if deployment happens to such a *dry-run only* machine. If so check if `ansible_check_mode` is set, if not exit with a message otherwise proceed. This is everything but a nice approach.

Is there something similar to `ansible_ssh_extra_args` for Ansible args I missed?

At least nothing is mentioned in the docs at [Connecting to hosts: behavioral inventory parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

Any alternatives?

Comment: According "_The best I was able to come up with ..._" it seems you have already implemented something which also seems to work. Do you mind to share it here? By doing this it might be possible to provide an alternative as requested to the currently unknown.

Comment: @U880D as a matter of fact "*The best I was able to come up with...*" just points to an idea and is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) it seems not to be possible to force `ansible_check_mode` to `true` based on `group_vars`, `set_fact` or others, except [enforcing on task level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks).

This will one leave with the already mentioned approach of

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  pre_tasks:

  - name: Check Mode
    fail:
      msg: The system may not be provisioned according to the CMDB status.
    when: not ansible_check_mode and 'test' in group_names

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: ansible_check_mode
```

and resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Check Mode] ****************************************************
fatal: [test.example.com]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: The system may not be provisioned according to the CMDB status.
```

or when running with `--check` of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  ansible_check_mode: true
```

Such is also a feasible approach to prevent generally the execution under certain user accounts

```yaml
  pre_tasks:

  - name: Check Ansible User
    fail:
      msg: Do not execute under root!
    when: ansible_user == 'root'
```

or [when a `--limit` has to be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57395307/6771046).

**Further Documentation**

- [Set the order of task execution in Ansible with two keywords](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-pretasks-posttasks)
- [Playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html)
- [`fail` module – Fail with custom message](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html)