# How to mark an Ansible Role in a Collection as deprecated?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-galaxy, ansible-collections

I manage an Ansible Collection on Ansible Galaxy with multiple roles in it and want to mark some of those roles as deprecated. How can I do this?

In the Ansible documentation there is only a solution for [modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/module_lifecycle.html#deprecating-modules-and-plugins-in-a-collection).

Can this be adopted to the roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such framework AFAIK. But, you can easily create one on your own. Use the configuration parameter [DEPRECATION_WARNINGS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#deprecation-warnings). For example, declare defaults

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/defaults/main/deprecation.yml
foo_deprecation_warnings: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.config', 'DEPRECATION_WARNINGS')}}"
foo_deprecation:
  removal_version: 2.0.0
  warning_text: Read the release notes on how to migrate
```

, create a task to display the deprecation warning

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/deprecation.yml
- name: Deprecation warning
  debug:
    msg: |
      [DEPRECATION WARNING]: This role will be removed from the collection in release {{ foo_deprecation.removal_version }}. {{ foo_deprecation.warning_text }}.
      Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in
      ansible.cfg.
```

, and include it conditionally

```yaml
shell> cat roles/foo/tasks/main.yml
- include_tasks: deprecation.yml
  when:
    - foo_deprecation
    - foo_deprecation_warnings
  run_once: true

- debug:
    msg: Role foo is running ...
```

When you run the role

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - foo
```

you'll see the deprecation warning

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [foo : include_tasks] ********************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-428/roles/foo/tasks/deprecation.yml for localhost

TASK [foo : Deprecation warning] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    [DEPRECATION WARNING]: This role will be removed from the collection in release 2.0.0. Read the release notes on how to migrate.
    Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in
    ansible.cfg.

TASK [foo : debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role foo is running ...

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

You can disable the deprecation warnings

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=false ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [foo : include_tasks] ********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [foo : debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role foo is running ...

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Declare an empty dictionary if you don't want a role to display a deprecation warning

```yaml
foo_deprecation:
```

or don't include the task *deprecation.yml*.

Answer (score 0):

For [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/index.html) as provider of the content there is an option available to [Deprecate Content](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/deprecate.html)

> *You can deprecate Collections and Role repositories that you own from the ‘My Content’ page. ...*

Just follow the documentation.

---

Since [Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) are for

> *... group your content in roles, you can easily reuse them and share them with other users.*

and just source code, scripts, YAML files, there is nothing like a deprecation warning message for the content itself.

To work around one could [implement `pre_tasks`](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-pretasks-posttasks) together with specific messages and behavior. In example like

```yaml
  pre_tasks:

  - name: Check Ansible User
    fail:
      msg: Do not execute under root!
    when: ansible_user == 'root'
```

Together with [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) it can be used to [`fail` with Custom Message](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html), [`assert` that given expressions are `true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) or in order to [print `WARNING`s from playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033923/).

Since there is no module to print `WARNING` messages out-of-box, it needs to be implemented via a [Filter Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/filter.html) which can be easily [Develop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins)ed and as shown within the given link or as an own [Custom Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html) [`warn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036628/6771046). One may take note that such approach will create further dependencies for a Role and which would need to be resolved before too.

A workaround for that could be simply

```yaml
  pre_tasks:

  - name: DEPRECATION WARNING
    fail:
      msg: Use v2 instead!
    when: VERSION == 'v1'
    ignore_errors: true
```

**Other Q&A**

- [Only allow `--check` and / or `--diff` for certain Ansible hosts / groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75537677/6771046)